# R plotting / graphics guidw

Tags: r, plot

I often have (very basic) issues while plotting in R and I'm tired of (what I feel is) spamming stackoverflow with lame plotting issues. I'm determined to end it once and for all!

When I google around for help on R plotting, I've been very unsatisfied with the general results I receive. Are there any recommendations for online resources that could offer me a good reference for plotting in R? Looking for super basic information, possibly more complicated stuff as well.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1):

There are several books worth reading.  Start with Paul Murrell's [R Graphics](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/RG2e/).  Then read Hadley Wickham's [ggplot2 book](http://ggplot2.org/book/).  Then Deepayan Sarkar's [lattice book](http://dsarkar.fhcrc.org/lattice/book/).

Comment: Do you know of any free online resources? Those are perfect, but I don't really need that extensive of detail, especially not at that price.

Answer (score 0):

[Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/index.html) is a great resource, it has sections on Basic Graphs and Advanced Graphs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use and develop the [R Programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming/Graphics) wikibook. This is a project of a collaborative handbook.

Answer (score 0):

I enjoyed this page for the basics: http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~joseff/rstudy/week4.html

It has more context than the package description for graphics and lattice.